# How to Mock GetBlobsByHierarchy() from Azure.Storage.Blobs?

Tags: azure, .net-core, mocking, azure-blob-storage, xunit.net

Could anyone please help me to mock `GetBlobsByHierarchy()` from Azure.Storage.Blobs? I need to create mock for the following code in xUnit:

```
BlobContainerClient container;

var resultSegment = container.GetBlobsByHierarchy(prefix:prefix, delimiter:"/")
                             .AsPages(continuationToken, segmentSize);
```

The details of the code is in this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list?tabs=dotnet) from Microsoft site. I tried to mock this `GetBlobsByHierarchy()` function but failed. Please give me some idea/sample.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problems. I have created stub class for BlobContainerClient class and overwrite the required functions..

Below are the code sample,

```
 public sealed class StubBlobContainerClient : BlobContainerClient
 {
       public override Pageable<BlobHierarchyItem> GetBlobsByHierarchy(BlobTraits traits = BlobTraits.None, BlobStates states = BlobStates.None, string delimiter = null, string prefix = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
       { 
          //implementation
       }
 }
```

You are always welcome to share any other way to resolve the issue.

Comment: Hello, What are you returning in this method? How are you adding the BlobHierarchyItem in Pageable?